# How to transfer files out of a Github repository?

Tags: github

I don't know how to "disable" github off my code, because I tried to move them out of a folder, but they still have github changes, and other github related stuff. I want to make them just simple files on a computer (html, css, js), with no Github.

Comment: remove `.git` folder, if what you want to achieve is to disable git from tracking your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the folder .git in the top folder, and it wont track git anymore.

```
rm -rf .git
```